# How to giva a time accurate timer in Fire Monkey?

Tags: delphi, timer, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I have to display a timer in 10th second for a sport competition. I have do this using the OnTimer event of a TTimer. the interval is set to 100. My routine display the current min:sec.10th (ex.: 02:45.7 ) correctly but it seem that my timer loose about 4 second at each minutes if I comp. to normal clock.

There is a better way to get a time accuracy timer in Delphi XE2 (or XE3) ?

Comment: How do you calculate the elapsed time?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a timer to *display* the current value of the *clock*, but use a different approach to calculate the elapsed time.

You have to know that Windows timers are not *time accurate*, and even if you set it to elapse every 100 milliseconds, it can take more to fire the OnTimer event and even it can miss some intervals if for some reason elapses two or more times before your application process it.

You can, for example, use the system [high-resolution performance counter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to track times with nano-second accuracy.

You can also use the Delphi [TStopwatch](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Diagnostics.TStopwatch) class, which encapsulates the system calls and falls back to other method (GetTickCount) if the high resolution performance counter is not available in your machine.

Take also a look at the [How to Accurately Measure Elapsed Time Using High-Resolution Performance Counter](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/delphi-high-performance-timer-tstopwatch.htm) delphi.about.com article.

Comment: Thanks Very interesting, but my last question is: if I have to display a countdown timer, there still stay a lot calculation to do at each fire of OnTimer event and this will take time ?

Comment: @AlainV there is some calculation, yes, but it will take almost no time in any modern processor. You can also use another high performance counter to measure how much time it takes if you're interested in know more precisely. I bet it takes less than 0.1 millisecond. Is that much for you?

Comment: 1ms is by far not a problem, I need to display 10th second preciselly, thank !

Comment: With high precision, you will have much more precision than that, so you'r next _problem_ is to decide how to round it to only 10ths of a second, but that's a good problem to have ;)